# Angular JS programming

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**app.js**

```
(function(){

    var app=angular.module('tasks_list',[]);
    app.controller('TasksController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.taskList=localStorage.getItem('memoList');
        if($scope.taskList==undefined)
            $scope.taskList=[];

        console.log($scope.taskList);
        console.log($scope.taskList.length);
        $scope.addTask=function()
        {
            var task=document.getElementById('taskBox').value;
            console.log(task);
            $scope.taskList.push(task);
            console.log($scope.taskList);

            localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.setItem('memoList',$scope.taskList);
        };

    }]);


})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tasks_list">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv" ng-controller="TasksController">
        <h2>My To-do List</h2>
        <div class="promptMsg" ng-hide="taskList.length">Add your tasks here!</div>
        <form>
            <div id="list" ng-show="taskList.length" ng-repeat="task in taskList track by $index">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <p>{{task}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="addList">
                <input type="text" id="taskBox" autofocus/>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-click="addTask()"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Remove completed tasks"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/src/angular-local-storage.js"></script> -->

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above app.js file, I am getting error msg

> undefined is not a function

at `$scope.taskList.push(task);`.

Also, at `<p>` inside `div id="list"`, I want to add array element, but I am getting text letter by letter.

Please suggest whats wrong in the code.

Comment: So `$scope.taskList` is clearly not an array !

Comment: how? please elaborate.

Comment: You have to parse what gets retured from localStorage. It's just a string now. `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memoList'))`

Comment: ya @cfj,and string have no ```push()``` method

Comment: thanks.. but it is giving error "unexpected token". It is not recognizing parse().

Comment: cfj and kuldip.. dats right.. I would have to parse . .but can u please edit code for how to parse in angular js. I am getting error for parse() as undefined function.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Dont do this: `var task=document.getElementById('taskBox').value;` -- instead use `ng-model` in the view to bind it to your scope.
- Don't access localStorage directly. Use the `$window` service or a third-party module like `ngStorage`.
- Don't use the `ngClick` on a submit. Either use `ngSubmit` or `ngClick`, but don't mix them.

I have updated your code to get it working, but disabled the sessionStorage calls because they are blocked in the Stackoverflow sandbox.

```js
(function(){

    var app=angular.module('tasks_list',[]);
  
    app.controller('TasksController',['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
  
      // cannot use localStorage in sanbox
      //$scope.taskList = angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem('memoList'));
        
      if($scope.taskList==undefined)
          $scope.taskList=[];

      console.log($scope.taskList);
      console.log($scope.taskList.length);
      $scope.addTask = function(newTask) {
        
            console.log(newTask);
            $scope.taskList.push(newTask);
            console.log($scope.taskList);
        
            $scope.newTask = "";

            // cannot use localStorage in sandbox
            //$window.localStorage.clear();
            //$window.localStorage.setItem('memoList', angular.toJson($scope.taskList));
        };

    }]);


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="tasks_list">

    <div id="mainDiv" ng-controller="TasksController">
        <h2>My To-do List</h2>
        <div class="promptMsg" ng-hide="taskList.length">Add your tasks here!</div>
        <form>
            <div id="list" ng-show="taskList.length" ng-repeat="task in taskList track by $index">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <p>{{task}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="addList">
                <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" autofocus/>
                <a ng-click="addTask(newTask)">Add</a>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Remove completed tasks"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{{taskList}}
</div>
```

Here is a link to the same code, with the localStorage lines un-commented, otherwise it is the exact same code here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XOkihsxdHqcxXJyYtG1w?p=preview

As expected, you can refresh the browser and the list will be loaded from localStorage.

Comment: thanks martin, but its showing unexpected token syntax error for fromJson().

Comment: And undefined function for fromJSON().

Comment: I updated my original answer to include a link to a plunkr with the localStorage lines un-commented. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token d
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.nb [as fromJson]                                      This error msg I am getting for fromJson() function

Comment: your code is running as expected in plunker. but giving an error when i copied it to my editor and tried to execute it.

Comment: Please post your code to plunkr, jsfiddle or any other code playground -- reproducing the errors you are seeing?

Comment: Please post the changes you made to your code. It should be angular.fromJson()  or JSON.parse() not Object.parse().

Comment: As well, delete the memoList key in localStorage for the domain you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that localStorage can only store strings. When you need to save an array you therefore need to convert it into a string first, using `JSON.stringify()`. When retrieving the string from the storage you convert it back into an array with `JSON.parse()`.

Please see [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9PVl1s6U59qJdC9eIVMM?p=info) for a demonstration.